# Google Tag Manager for 2 separate webapps on same host

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have 2 web apps which work together (seamlessly from the users' perspective), deployed to the same tomcat instance. I have added the google tag manager code to both their respective Index.html files. One of them works and the other does not (By that I mean the console does not appear to be doing any GTM activity when I hit the URL)

I'm new to TagManager so maybe I am being naive. Could it be that I need a separate Tag manager registration for each app?

```
   <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MY-CODE" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MY-CODE');</script>
```

Comment: You did not anonymize the GTM code in the noscript tag. When I call this I get a 404 error which suggests your container is not published (although in that case it should not work at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. GTM does not really care about the host or what app this is unless you have configured your triggers to depend on the host name, or app name. Even then you should see some action, namely that a dataLayer object is populated with a few standard events (gtm.js, gtm.dom and gtm.load).

Can't really says what causes your problem, but it's not that you'd need multiple containers (although in many instances multiple containers per app are a good idea, but that's a matter of how you organize your tags, not something dictated by the technology).

Comment: Thanks will accept later (too early). Good to rule it out.

Comment: Further to this, and just to give you a laugh, the second app simply had not been deployed in months. I was asked to investigate this; I just made certain reasonable assumptions